# Svelte +layout.server.ts type errors in new project

Tags: typescript, svelte

I setup a new project using the steps

```
npm create svelte@latest myapp
cd myapp
npm install
npm run dev
```

I want to load something before page load (eg on the server) so I do what it says. I created `+layout.server.ts` and copy pasted from the docs

```
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';
 
export const load = (({ locals }) => {
  console.log(locals)
  if (!locals.user) {
    throw redirect(307, '/login');
  }
}) satisfies LayoutServerLoad;
```

This gives me errors.

1. `Individual declarations in merged declaration 'LayoutServerLoad' must be all exported or all local.`
2. `Binding element 'locals' implicitly has an 'any' type`

I know `locals` *can* be typed from `app.d.ts` but I also have no idea how to use that file. I don't know how to import declarations from it.

Comment: Weird, I cannot reproduce the error you saw. Where do you see the error? In IDE hint or vite server's terminal log?

Comment: You should not need to do anything regarding the types from `app.d.ts`, it extends existing types; all its declarations should become available automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment interface Locals and write your properties inside, like this:

[image: properties example]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)